# How to write own font to support newly introduced currency?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Recently I came through this, including the currency symbol in pdf. I know it can be achievable by using img src html tag.

I just want to achieve by writing own font OR kind of helper file in PHP.

Need experts advice.

I am looking for indian rupee symbol in mPdf creation.

Comment: Something like this? ₹

Comment: Yes, I use to display using this HTML entity code (&#8377) and  <div style="font-family:dejavusanscondensed">&#x20b9;</div> . When I send this HTML to pdf creation it comes as ? instead of INR symbol.

Comment: Why send the entity code when, if it's all UTF8 anyway, you can just type the symbol?

Comment: After seen your post, have tried in application. In HTML i can able to see the rupee symbol, where as in pdf its ?(qn mark).

Comment: Sound like either a character set or encoding issue; might help: https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/input-encoding.html

Answer (score 0):

It might help

Find and open classes\pdf\PdfGenerator.php

Find code:

Change:
const DEFAULT_FONT = 'helvetica';

To:
const DEFAULT_FONT = 'dejavusans';

Comment: Hi Rahul, I have already tried this, but there is no change in the output. BTW I have been tried in mPdf.